# Catchwords: Print first word from next page at bottom of current page

Tags: page-breaking, typography

I would like to typeset [catchwords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catchword). That is, I would like to put a “preview” of the next page’s first word at the bottom of every page.

An example taken from the Wikipedia page linked above:
[image: catchword]

The next page begins with the word (actually word fragment in this particular case) “dos”, and so that word is typeset flush right just below the text-block.

(How) can this be done with TeX?

Comment: try with "\looseness=-1" after the last word ?

Comment: Are you asking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catchword? “A catchword is a word placed at the foot of a handwritten or printed page that … anticipates the first word of the following page.”

Comment: @J.C.Salomon Yes, exactly!

Comment: A possible answer may be, how to add once (!) `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` automagically, if one word (not a whole line full of text) is otherwise printed on the next page.

Comment: @Erasm I don't think this is possible in (La)TeX, but maybe some LuaTeX trickery can help.

Comment: This is surely possible in LuaTeX: use the `post_linebreak_filter` to analyze the paragraphs and then `atbegshi` to find the last line on the page and add the information you've got from step one. Easy ;-))

Comment: @egreg surely you mean in an automated sense. I think that adding a different word to the footer of every page would be relatively easy once the list of words is known. Getting the list of words could be done by looking at the pdf.

Comment: @egreg Donald Arseneau made it possible in LaTeX ;-) (see my answer).

Answer (score 49):

You can use the [`fwlw`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fwlw) ("First Word, Last Word") package; a little example using a footer defined with the `fancyhdr` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage[a6paper,footskip=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fwlw}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[veryoldstyle]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\usebox\NextWordBox}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4-60]

\end{document}
```

An image of the first four pages:

[image]

The package gives access to the ﬁrst word on the current page (`\FirstWordBox`), the ﬁrst word on the next page (`\NextWordBox`), and the last word on the current page (`\LastWordBox`).

The package also offers a predefined page style `NextWordFoot` to read ahead to the first word on the next page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage[a6paper,footskip=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fwlw}
\usepackage[veryoldstyle]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{NextWordFoot}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4-60]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Who could imagine there's a package for this? `:)`

Comment: Is there another way of doing it without wasting the footer?

Comment: @NVaughan sure; in many ways. You can use, for example, the `background` package: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage[a6paper,footskip=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fwlw}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[veryoldstyle]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bottom]{background}

\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  color=black,
  opacity=1,
  vshift=64pt,
  contents={\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\usebox\NextWordBox}},
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4-60]

\end{document}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, cheers!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Great find!

Comment: This is *great*!

Comment: Excellent answer!  Note that often times it would be the first syllable, not the whole first word.  But that'd require a bit more work that I'm not entirely sure babel's hyphenation would handle correctly (since a one letter syllable often can't be left alone), and frankly, only a purist would notice :)

Comment: I did search for this exact question but somehow in the search results this question did not appear, that didn't certainly feel right, I mean certainly people must have thought about this. But perhaps my keywords were. So I went about composing my own question with examples. But as I composed my question, creating examples (manually with `marginnote` package, and I preview the question. This one appears in the box of related questions! Just makes me like LaTeX even more.