# Speech: last line reprinted on a new page

Tags: page

Is it possible to reprint the last line(s) of a page on a new page? I think this could be helpful for speeches...

```
\documentclass[paper=a5]{article}       
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think [catchwords](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75191) would be more useful than what you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you might find the `fwlw` package useful here (`> texdoc fwlw`) which gives you the first and last words on a page together with the first word on the next page. The author, Donald Arseneau (`asnd@triumf.ca`) has hinted that he will consider extending `fwlw` to cater for the first/last lines. You might wish to contact him.

Answer (score 4):

The main drawback with this approach is that it puts the entire speech into a BF buffer.  The `showframe` is just to check alignment.

I played around with `fancyhdr` and `\pagestyule{myheadings)` but finally went with `\afterpage`.

```
\documentclass[paper=a5]{article}       
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newsavebox{\BFbuffer}
\newsavebox{\headbox}

\newenvironment{drone}{\global\setbox\headbox=\hbox{Test}%
  \setbox\BFbuffer=\vbox\bgroup}%
{\egroup\newpage
 \loop\ifdim\ht\BFbuffer>0pt
   \setbox0=\vsplit\BFbuffer to \textheight
   \ifdim\ht\BFbuffer>0pt
     \setbox1=\copy0
     \setbox2=\vsplit1 to \dimexpr \ht1-\baselineskip\relax
     \global\setbox\headbox=\hbox{\usebox1}%
     \afterpage{\rlap{\raisebox{\dimexpr \topskip+\headsep}[0pt]{\usebox\headbox}}\vskip-\baselineskip}%
   \fi
   \unvbox0\pagebreak
 \repeat}

\begin{document}
\begin{drone}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{drone}
\end{document}
```